# NextJs : Functional component conditional return/rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hi I was thinking to redirect page if any next router query param is empty.
Like `localhost:3000/page?id=*null/empty*`

Here what I was doing :

```
export default function page() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id == null) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  });
return (......
```

but problem is that it renders page first then pushes to another page.
Any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove use of useEffect

```
export default function page() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;
 
  if (id == null) {
    router.push("/");
    return null;
  }
 
return (......
```

Comment: `Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`